# Is there a way to have "mutable" Fractions? - python

Tags: python, generator, mutable, fractions

**Is there a way to have a "mutable" `Fraction`?**

I've tried this but seem like the numerator/denominator in Fraction is not mutable.

```
>>> from fractions import Fraction
>>> x = Fraction(0,1)
>>> numerators = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> denominators = [9,8,7,6,5]
>>> for n,d in zip(numerators, denominators):
...     x.numerator+= n
...     x.denominator+= d
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
AttributeError: can't set attribute
```

I've been doing it as such because my numerators/denominators are from another function that returns a generator of Fractions.

```
>>> inputs = [Fraction(1,9), Fraction(2,8), Fraction(3,7), Fraction(4,6)]
>>> numerators, denominators = zip(*[(f.numerator, f.denominator) for f in inputs])
>>> x = Fraction(sum(numerators), sum(denominators))
>>> x
Fraction(7, 23)
```

(Note that I'm not adding `1/9 + 2/8 + 3/7 + 4/6`, I'm trying to sum the numerators and divide by the sum of the denominators)

**Is there a "mutable" Fraction?**

Comment: Is there a mutable integer?

Comment: But integer doesn't have a `numerator / denominator` =)

Comment: Is this fraction.Fraction? I don't see any imports.

Comment: But a numerator/denominator pair is just a precise way of denoting a point on a number line.

Comment: Also, isn't an integer just a fraction with denominator `1`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `numerator` and `denominator` are immutable for two reasons:

1. Other Python numeric types are immutable, including complex numbers which also consist of two simpler numeric values, and arbitrary-width quantities such as `long` and `Decimal`. Mutable fractions would be an exception.
2. Being able to individually mutate the numerator and the denominator would have the potential to invalidate the fraction, e.g. by making it denormalized, or by setting the denominator to zero.

In other words, there is no public API to mutate a `fractions.Fraction` object. If you really need a sum of individual numerators and denominators, which doesn't sound very useful, your second code snippet is a reasonable way to do it. A more exact rendition of the first snippet could look like this:

```
x = Fraction(sum(f.numerator for f in inputs),
             # add 1 since we start out with 0/1
             1 + sum(f.denominator for f in inputs))
```

Comment: @pat Can you elaborate on that? The OP's code sample initializes the accumulator `x` to `Fraction(0,1)`.

Comment: Well, the OP's second example does not, and since 0/1 = 0/42 = 0/x where x != 0, you could pick any non zero denominator to start...  It just shows that adding up the numerators and denominators gives a meaningless result.

Comment: @pat Yeah, I don't begin to understand why anyone would want to add up numerators and denominators. The interesting part of answering the question was trying to explain why fractions are immutable, and how that's not a real obstacle for implementing the request, strange as it is.

Answer (score 2):

Interesting idea, but it can be solved with some <s>simple</s> bad maths:

```
>>> x = Fraction(0,1)
>>> numerators = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> denominators = [9,8,7,6,5]
>>> for n,d in zip(numerators, denominators):
...     x += Fraction(n,x.denominator) # "Adding" to the numerator is adding a new fraction.
...     x = x/d # "adding" to the denominator is just dividing by the operand
```

You can [see this in practice here](http://ideone.com/UkZSel).

---

As I hinted at in my comment, but user4815162342 made much more clear, `Fractions` are immutable because *fractions* are immutable, much like `Integers` are immutable because the very concept of an integer number is immutable.

7 is 7 is 'seven' is `7`, so making a mutable object for an immutable idea is nonsensical. Much like `3/4` is 0.75 is 'three-quarters', no matter how you frame it the idea is the same, so making an object that represents a static concept be mutable wouldn't make sense.

What does make sense is using mathematics to modify them 3/4 with a denominator that is now 8, isn't a thing. Addition, multiplication or division of fractions is much more intuitive.

Comment: Doesn't this find the product of the denominators? That is, rather than `(a+b)/(c+d)` you're finding `(a+b)/(c*d)`

Comment: @Blckknght Yeah you are right, I just realised that... let me see what I can figure out.

Answer (score 1):

CPython 3.9.2 non-public API:

```
>>> from fractions import Fraction
>>> x = Fraction(0,1)
>>> numerators = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> denominators = [9,8,7,6,5]
>>> for n,d in zip(numerators, denominators):
...     x._numerator+= n
...     x._denominator+= d
>>> print(x)
15/36
```

please take care, because this is non-public way to do it and can be changed in future.

https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/fractions.py